# NSArray of many NSDictionary. What is the best way to find a NSDictionary with necessary value for given key?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Now I'm trying the following and it works.

```
    - (void)findDictionaryWithValueForKey:(NSString *)name {

         for (NSDictionary * set in myArray) {

            if ([[set objectForKey:@"title"] isEqualToString:name]) 
               \\do something

         }

    }
```

**EDIT:**
I've added one extra argument to the post of **bshirley**. Now it looks more flexible.

```
- (NSDictionary *)findDictionaryWithValue:(NSString*)name forKey:(NSString *)key {

    __block BOOL found = NO;
    __block NSDictionary *dict = nil;

    [self.cardSetsArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        dict = (NSDictionary *)obj;
        NSString *title = [dict valueForKey:key];
        if ([title isEqualToString:name]) {
            found = YES;
            *stop = YES;
        }
    }];

    if (found) {
        return dict;
    } else {
        return nil;
    }

}
```

Comment: a shorter title and the question actually in the body would be preferable

Comment: there is no "best way", there are a variety of ways to do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's one possible implementation using newer API.  (I also modified the method to actually return the value).  Provided mostly to demonstrate that API.  The assumption is that the title is unique to one dictionary within your array.

```
- (NSDictionary *)findDictionaryWithValueForKey:(NSString *)name {
  // ivar: NSArray *myArray;
  __block BOOL found = NO;
  __block NSDictionary *dict = nil;

  [myArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    dict = (NSDictionary *)obj;
    NSString *title = [dict valueForKey:@"title"];
    if ([title isEqualToString:name]) {
      found = YES;
      *stop = YES;
    }
  }];

  if (found) {
    return dict;
  } else {
    return nil;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thats great, I use your code and and I've slightly modified for more flexibility in may class to manage content of this root array. I add it as an answer with reference to you reply.

Answer (score 8):

Use `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` method of the array to get all the dictionaries that satisfy your requirement.

```
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@" title MATCHES[cd] %@", name];
NSArray * matches = [myArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Now `matches` is the array of dictionaries that have the `title` key equal to `name`.

Comment: a nice way in the case which there may be multiple with the same title!

Answer (score 0):

I will also suggest this way,it would be better if you use a break statement,

```
- (void)findDictionaryWithValueForKey:(NSString)name {

     for (NSDictionary * set in myArray) {

        if ([[set objectForKey:@"title"] isEqualToString:name]) 
           \\do something
           break;
     }

}
```

As per the NSArray documentation,

```
valueForKey:

Returns an array containing the results of invoking valueForKey: using key on each of the array's objects.
- (id)valueForKey:(NSString *)key
Parameters

key

    The key to retrieve.

Return Value

The value of the retrieved key.
Discussion

The returned array contains NSNull elements for each object that returns nil.
Availability

    * Available in Mac OS X v10.3 and later.
```

**EDIT:**

try this,

```
[myArray valueForKey:@"name"];
```

//this will return array of values, but this actually differ from what to want

Comment: Actually my code works, but if I need to drill down it's getting crazy to understand. Anyway thank you for you note about "break" in my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
    - (void)findDictionaryWithValueForKey:(NSString)name {

        for (NSDictionary * set in myArray) {


            NSString *s=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[set objectForKey:@"title"]];
            if ([s isEqualToString:name]) 
                \\do something

            }

            OR 
            if (s == name]) 
                \\do something

            }



    }
```